# keypress event to chrome addressbar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a action in keypress event on chrome addressbar. How to achieve this using chrome extension development?

PS: My use case is if user press Ctrl+enter in the addressbar, i need to initiate my function/action.

Comment: Read the Docs: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands

Comment: For your case: Capture the key event, then check if focus is on address bar.

Comment: how i suppose to capture the key event using commands? i am bit confused! Also i don't have any idea how to capture if the focus on addressbar! :(

Comment: Can you post what code you have so far? Or atleast the relevant code.

Comment: Regarding the focus, how much Javascript knowledge do you have? If you   are learning JS while creating an Extension for Chrome, you will have a hard time...start with a simple website and some JS.

Comment: How do you check if the focus is on the address bar? AFAIK, that's not possible. You can only work with the DOM.